# Information from a userform to be populated into a row based on a set namerange

Tags: excel, range, userform

I have a workbook that currently when i double click on a cell it brings up the userform, all the data in the user form is then populated into desired columns in the work book.

I would like to change it so that I can click on a command button in the sheet, bring up the userform and then when i click submit it will populate into the correct category (ie: dozer, dumptruck) etc i have made name ranges for these groups in ("H:H"), there is a combo box on the form named 'group' that will display one of these categories.

The code i have currently which works fine is below, i just want to be able to do it from 1 button, rather than double clicking on the cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'populate machine info into correct category & sort

'?????


'populate machine info to diary
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 7) = TextBox1.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 8) = Group.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 10) = TextBox3.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 11) = TextBox2.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 12) = TextBox4.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 13) = TextBox5.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 14) = TextBox6.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 15) = DTPicker1.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 24) = DTPicker2.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 25) = TextBox7.Value
On Error Resume Next
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 27) = TextBox8.Value

Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Group

    .AddItem "DUMPTRUCKS"
.AddItem "BOBCATS"
.AddItem "DOZERS"
.AddItem "EXCAVATORS"
.AddItem "GENSETS"
.AddItem "GRADERS"
.AddItem "LIGHTINGPLANTS"
.AddItem "LOADERS"
.AddItem "PUMPS"
.AddItem "ROLLERS"
.AddItem "SCRAPERS"
.AddItem "SERVICETRUCKS"
.AddItem "TIPPERTRUCKS"
.AddItem "WATERCARTS"
.AddItem "WATERTRUCKS"

End With

'return values from service board into adding plant form
Sheet4.Cells(rownumber5, 7).Activate
UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
UserForm2.Group.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
UserForm2.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
UserForm2.TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
UserForm2.TextBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
UserForm2.TextBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
UserForm2.TextBox6.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
On Error Resume Next
UserForm2.DTPicker1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
On Error Resume Next
UserForm2.DTPicker2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
UserForm2.TextBox7.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
UserForm2.TextBox8.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Value


End Sub
```

Any ideas on this would be appreciated...

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: What is stopping you from putting a command button on the sheet and calling the code from the button?

Comment: At the moment the code puts the information into the row from which the cell in ("G:G:) is double clicked on. not based on what category it is in.